# Regex combination to format a string exactly like a HTML renderer

Tags: java, html, regex

I've been trying around to get this working with regular expressions but I just keep failing, so maybe someone more experienced with this can help?

How can I render a string close to the way any webbrowser renders a html string? 
Example HTML:

```
<html>
  Hel
lo 
  how
 are   you
</html>
```

Is rendered:

```
Hel lo how are you
```

I want it to be

```
Hello how are you
```

So the difference to html is that a newline without explicit spaces is just removed. In java this string would look like this:

```
\tHel\nlo \n  how\n are    you
```

My current solution:

```
// remove linebreaks and tabs and any leading or trailing whitespace
// this is necessary to avoid converting \t or \n to a space
script = script.replaceAll("\\s+\n\\s+", "");
script = script.replaceAll("\\s+\t\\s+", "");
// remove any length of whitespace and replace it with one
script = script.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
// rewmove leading and trailing whitespaces
script = script.trim();
```

Has only one problem: 
If I have a line with a trailing space followed by a newline and some more text, the trailing space will be removed:

```
Hello \nhow are you?
```

will be reduced to

Hellohow are you

So, using underscore (_) as space marker the following should be true:

```
_ = _
__ = _
\t\n_ = _
_\t\n = _
\t_\n = _
_\t_\n_ = _
\n = // nothing
\t = // nothing
\t\n = // nothing
```

Our goal is a script editor where I can format freely. However the script is later rendered to a string and there newlines and tabs should not show. Only explicit spaces should show and they need to be collapsed to one.

What combination of replaceAll(regex, string) would I need to use?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you could just remove newlines and tabs in a first step and in a second replace every group of spaces with a single one?

Comment: The problem is that you are confused about which whitespace gets ignored. In reality, all runs of whitespace characters get collapsed to a single space, and then the first space after the start tag gets ignored, as well as the last space before the end tag. That's it.

Comment: Yes you're right. I've updated my question. There is ONE difference to html in what I want to happen: A newline or tab that is not lead or trailed by a space should collapse to nothing.

Comment: @Pete, I think Sebastian's approach is correct. Try `s.replaceAll("[\n\r\t]+", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ")`. It passes your tests.

Comment: This worked for a couple of lines. `str.replaceAll("\\n", "").replaceAll("^\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ")`. Anchor is added not to add whitespace at the start of the line.

Comment: I suppose these suggestions is still not what you eventually want. What about tab in the middle of the string? For example "Hello\thow are you", using the answers is will produce "Hellohow are you". I think `input.replaceAll("[\n\r]+", "").replaceAll("\t+", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim()` the closest

Comment: Do you mean this `str.trim().replaceAll("\\s* \\s*", " ");` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regex to ensure there is a [Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/0020/) `0x20` character within a series of whiatespaces:

```
\s* \s*
```

Java code:

```
str.trim().replaceAll("\\s* \\s*", " ");
```